# SKPhysicsBody(bodies: collisionBitMask does not work

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sprite, skphysicsbody

I have situation where I need to create two SKPhysicsBody for a single texture because the collision response need to be different

```
 let leftBigBox = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf :CGSize(width: 490, height: 90) , center:bCenterPoint )

    leftBigBox.contactTestBitMask = category_kitty
    leftBigBox.categoryBitMask = category_train
    leftBigBox.collisionBitMask = category_kitty | category_track

    let rightSmallBox = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf :CGSize(width: 100, height: 45) , center:sCenterPoint )
   rightSmallBox.categoryBitMask = category_wagon
   rightSmallBox.collisionBitMask = category_kitty | category_track
   rightSmallBox.contactTestBitMask = category_kitty

    physicsBody=SKPhysicsBody(bodies: [leftBigBox,rightSmallBox])
```

but `didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact)` does not detect when my kitty hits the child node. I can see the debug mode it is happening but the delegate won't print , if I specify the  `collisionBitMask` , `contactTestBitMask` for the parent physicsBody  it works but my goal is to split them into two
* I tried using joints and two different texture the performance is so bad

These are the values for kitty

```
 physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = category_kitty
 physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = category_wagon | category_border | category_train
 physicsBody!.collisionBitMask =  category_border | category_wagon | category_train
```

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1519736-init

> "The properties on the children, such as mass or friction, are
>   ignored. Only the shapes of the child bodies are used."

This means that the bitMasks you have set up on the 2 individual physics bodies are not retained when you create the new physicsBody via:

`physicsBody=SKPhysicsBody(bodies: [leftBigBox,rightSmallBox])`

(as KnightOfdragon says, it uses only the *shape* of the physicsbodies in the array to create the shape of the new physicsBody. You then have to set all the properties of the new physics body - none of the properties from the bodies being joined are used).

So you might be better off either joining the 2 physics bodies with a joint of some sort (if you do not know how to do this, ask a new question) or using some other method to determine which part of your object has bit hit by kitty.

Comment: Yes, joining multiple bodies only joins the paths, not the attributes

Comment: I would make kitty 2 SKNodes so that it could have 2 SKPhysicsBodies

Comment: thanks for response...that makes it clear is there a easy way to find where the sprite got hit if we treat it as single physical body